# How to update xml according to XSD only known at runtime?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

The goal is to **insert some element into an existing xml** document according to a given XSD as part of a java appliaction.

The problem is: the **concrete XSD is only known at runtime**, so the standard solutions like jaxb don't work since they handle XSDs known at compile-time.

The only structural information I have at compile-time is the structure of the element to insert and the name of the parent element. The order and names of the siblings of that element is only available inside the XSD at runtime.

From a higher level I would say the task can be done in the following steps:

1. parse xml to build document tree
2. determine the right place where to insert the element (*<-- this is the hard part*) according to the given XSD
3. insert the element
4. write the document as xml

The problem is step 2. I found a similar question asking for a solution of that step: [How to load XML tags order from XSD with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461374/how-to-load-xml-tags-order-from-xsd-with-java) but this question has no answer.

Comment: What would you do if you know XSD at compile time? How would you use JAXB to implement the #2?

Comment: Check out this: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.xerces.xs.XSModel

Comment: If the XSD would be fix at compile time I would create JAXB bindings, unmarshal the xml, update the content tree and marshal it as last step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [XML Schema Object Model](https://xsom.java.net/) to figure out the order among sibling elements. I have used it in a project to determine the cardinality of child elements, which was important when transforming XML to JSON and vice versa.

It takes some effort to grok it, but it works quite well.

**UPDATE**

I think XSOM is part of Xerces, or at least Xerces implements Post Schema Validation Infoset (PSVI). Given that you parse the input XML document using a schema aware parser, you can access the PSVI and analyze it. Read more [here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html#faq-4).

Comment: When looking on the projects page it seems that the project is dead: there is no download page anymore and the JIRA contains only a small amount of issues from some years ago.

Comment: my current approach is now to use xerces to get an ordered list of siblings for the "to-be-inserted"-element and then insert it at the right position

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following.

Do not use JAXB. Go down to DOM. Just parse document, validate it against you XSD at runtime. The validation will probably throw exception that contains some information about location of problematic fragment. Use this information to locate the parent node in DOM and add missing node.

I did not try this myself and afraid that the implementation will not be as easy as this short description but hope that it is doable.

So, good luck. I'd be glad to know how you will solve the problem.